# this keyword passed as an argument

Tags: java, this

Can someone help me understand how the script reads `this` as `toString()`? I am a  bit confused about the logic of this.

```
public Fraction(int numerator, int denominator) {
    this.numerator = numerator;
    this.denominator = denominator;
}

@Override                      
public String toString() {
    return numerator + " / " + denominator;
}

public void print() {
    System.out.println(this); // works the same as with toString() passed as an argument
}
```

Comment: The only difference is, you don't pass the result of toString(), you just pass the instance of your class on which a toString will be executed

Answer (score 3):

Because that's what [`println`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println(java.lang.Object)) does when it receives an `Object` (that is, an instance of any class which is not a `String` or `Integer`, `Double` and co.).

`System.out.println(someObject)` calls [`String.valueOf(someObject)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object)) which, in turns, calls the object's `toString` method.